# How to re-style Infragistics XamDocManager splitPane and TabContent Pane

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am Using Infragistics XamDocManager and Its Default behavior is coming i want to re-style the tab and borders but i am not able to design
Below is my code and 
also Image with Tab 
Image  : [image: MyInfragisticsTab Style]

```
<igDock:XamDockManager ToolWindowLoaded="XamDockManager_ToolWindowLoaded" AllowMaximizeFloatingWindows="True" AllowMinimizeFloatingWindows="True">
        <igDock:DocumentContentHost>
            <igDock:SplitPane Style="{StaticResource mysplit}">
                <igDock:TabGroupPane >`<igDock:ContentPane Header="Title Data" Style="{StaticResource myNavgi}"/>
                    <igDock:ContentPane Header="Job Title Data" Style="{StaticResource myNavgi}"/>
                    <igDock:ContentPane Header="Designation Data" Style="{StaticResource myNavgi}"/>
                </igDock:TabGroupPane>
            </igDock:SplitPane>
        </igDock:DocumentContentHost>
    </igDock:XamDockManager>`
```

Comment: You should be able to right-click on the XamDocManager in design mode in VS and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy. This should copy the default template into your XAML markup and you can then edit it as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank You .itsI Works so many things i did...But and  i need to style the tab showing in XamDocManager...I want to change the background color of Tab

Comment: Up i want to change "Title Data" Background how can i do that

Comment: You need to modify the control template.